# I need to run a shell command from python and store the output in a string or file

Tags: python, shell, unix

I will use **ls** as an example:

I tried:

```
str = call("ls")
```

str stored 0.

I tried:

```
str = call("ls>>txt.txt")
```

but had no luck (an error occured & txt.txt wasn't created).

How do I perform this straight-forward task.

[I had imported **call**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: `call` simply runs a command in the shell, then returns the return value of that command.  Since your `ls` was successful, `call('ls')` returned 0.

If you are simply trying to run `ls`, then I would suggest using `glob`:

```
from glob import glob
file_list = glob('*')
```

If you want to do something more complicated, my suggestion would be to use `subprocess.Popen()` like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ls_proc = Popen('ls', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = ls_proc.communicate()
```

Note, in the `stdout` and `stderr` keywords, `PIPE` can be replaced with any file-like object, so you can send the output to a file if you want.  Also, you should read about Popen.communicate() prior to using it since if the command you call hangs, your python routine will also hang.

Comment: Once you have the process open by calling Popen, the object that is returned will have a communicate() attribute.  As for piping to a file, you can use `ls_proc = Popen('ls', stdout=open('outfile.txt', 'w'))`.

Comment: Can you show me the errors?

Comment: I apologize, it's working :) I'm not very practised with python syntax.